# Laravel aws s3 bucket - Error executing "PutObject" on error

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Thank you in advance

I have my s3 bucket and set the credentials to the below environment variable

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=
AWS_BUCKET=
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=s3
```

I have installed `"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0"`

when I am trying to upload the file with the below code

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($request->file('image')), 'public');
```

it is giving me below error

```
local.ERROR: Error executing "PutObject" on "{bucket_path}/images/blogs/b1fdcce2ebfaf7cbf6e929789935be9bblog.jpg"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60:  (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) {"exception":"[object] (Aws\\S3\\Exception\\S3Exception(code: 0)
```

Comment: Curl Error 60 : The remote server's SSL certificate or SSH md5 fingerprint was deemed not OK. This error code has been unified with CURLE_SSL_CACERT since 7.62.0. Its previous value was 51.

Comment: I am working on local so what should i change, can you please help

Comment: https://www.mynotepaper.com/php-curl-error-code-60-ssl-certificate-problem-solved

This has resolved my issue

Comment: i am glad you solved it :) sorry i wasn't available.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time @MandeepGill, you had given me a way to solve the error